# Mac app costs so much CPU after sleep

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer

My app runs well at launch. Normally, it only use 0.2% CPU while running.

But keep using the app day after day, it now costs 15% CPU, which is really huge for me.

I think thing goes wrong, after I sleep my Macbook many times. I don't turn off my Macbook.

I don't know where to investigate this bug?

PS: my app uses many NSTimer, which is added to NSRunLoopCommonModes

Thanks,

Comment: The question isn't very clear on what the issue is... does it only use 15% CPU *after* first going to sleep while it was running?

Comment: normally, it only use 0.2% CPU while running. But keep using the app day after day, it now cost 15% CPU, which is really huge for me.

Answer (score 5):

The only real answer is: Profile and see where the time is being used.

Answer (score 1):

In sleep mode, the operating system and other programs generally don't do much or anything. If your app continues to loop and ignores sleep mode, your percentual CPU usage will go up because other programs use less.

Ideally your app should check for sleep mode and then adjust its behaviour, e.g. suspend the loop.